Stability of this complex gas giant moon system
Let us consider this gas giant moon system:
Gas giant:

7 Jupiter masses
1.37 Jupiter radii

Moon 1

0.317 earth masses
775332 km semi-major axis
40 hrs orbital period

Moon 2

0.2 earth masses
1015972 km semi-major axis
60 hrs orbital period

Moon 3

0.25 earth masses
1331300 km semi-major axis
90 hrs orbital period

Moon 4

0.2 earth masses
1744497 km semi-major axis
135 hrs orbital period

Moon 5

0.1 earth masses
2285938 km semi-major axis
202.5 hrs orbital period

As you can see each moon is in a 2:3 orbital resonance with it's neighbor, which as far as I am aware should be one of the most stable. That being said I tried running this simulation in universe sandbox and the system loses stability rather quickly at a speed of 1 year per second. Given that I cannot dismiss it being an inaccuracy error caused by the speed, I'd like if you could help me shed some light on this.
Would this moon system remain stable in the long term? And in case it isn't would having all the moons in a laplace resonance be better?

The masses of the moons are quite significant so that their mutual interaction will play a role. Their surface acceleration is irrelevant for determining stability of the system. Their semi-major axis might be much more interesting (though it can be deduced from the planets and the moons' masses). Jupiter's main moons have a 1:2:4:~9 resonance.

@planetmaker i'll add them

If you want to dive into stability analysis a bit deeper, maybe you can start with https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211379721009785 and references therein... it's not trivial :)
